# Происхождение слова "собака"

Tags: этимология

Почему в русском языке собака называется собакой и от какого слова произошло это название?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У слова "собака" не русское происхождение. Считается, что оно попало в русский язык из языка скифов и звучало "сбака" или "збака". Обозначало оно всю ту же собаку.
В старорусском же языке существовало слово "пес".

Comment: Не "не русское", а нерусского происхождения.

Answer (score 4):

Бачить—видеть
Бачити(ь)ся--- видеться
Побачение  - свидание.

Польский  видеться - zobaczyć
Собачиться—аналог свидеться. А уж потом ругаться.
Собака, собач(и)ка—участник.
Собчак
Собачник.
Общак.
Об(ч)щаться—видеться.
Сообщество .
Сообщать. Сообчить.
Собака именно для сообщества. Что самому не бегать и смотреть.
Чисто смысловые переходы.

Однако Фасмер лепит только от чего либо, лишь бы не от исходного.

ох уж это немецкое чудо-этимо лажа.

Answer (score 2):

"Язык скифов" нуждается в уточнении.
Под скифами греки понимали группу народов разного происхождения и языка, объединённых только общим ареалом обитания и культурными связями.
Сейчас под термином "скифы" обычно объединяют различные ираноязычные племена и по одной из версий "собака" действительно может восходить к древнеиранскому корню "kabak". Но эта версия активно опровергается Трубачевым. (См. Фасмер)

Answer (score 2):

по казахски иiс баққан означает следящий за запахом, возможно слово "собака" тюркского происхождения

Answer (score 2):

Л. Успенский в книге "Слово о словах" приводит одну из версий происхождения языков, по которой слова во всех языках состоят из одних и тех же первичных, простейших, многозначащих звукокорней. Для однозначного определения явления или предмета люди присоединяли эти звукокорни друг к другу, образуя современные слова. Например: само-лет, везде-ход. По мере расхождения людей несколько изменялись сами звукокорни (например слово со значением "есть, имеется, существует, является": в кирг., казах., татар. - бар; узбек. - bor; англ. - bear, be; тур., азерб. - var; норвеж., швед. - ha, har; дат., исланд. - er), выбор их и порядок присоединения; первичные звукокорни забывались, сливались в современные корни, переходили в приставки, суффиксы, окончания - так образовались различные современные языки. Чем меньше язык был подвержен внешнему влиянию, тем больше в нем осталось этих первичных неискаженных звукокорней. По моему мнению одним из таких языков является киргизский; к тому же К. К. Юдахин составил прекрасный и очень подробный словарь, который я использую в своих исследованиях. Теперь к ответу на вопрос:
са, саа - дат. падеж от сен (ты) - тебе;
баа - цена, ценность; оценка;
ач- - открывать, раскрывать; отпирать; перенесенное - обнаруживать;
ачык - открытый (открывающий, обнаруживающий - Т.В.А.).
собачка (белорус. - сабачка) - са баа ачык - тебе ценность обнаруживающий.
От корня "ач" произошли: русск. очи - глаза (ед. ч. око); латыш. asc - глаз; испан. ojo - глаз; итал. occhi - глаза; англ. watch - смотреть; нем. wach - бодрствующий, пробудиться и др. Украинское бач - видишь - баа (ценность) ач (раскрывай, обнаруживай).

Comment: Вы хоть иногда придерживайтесь темы вопроса. Надоедает уже читать про киргизский язык там, где его рядом не лежало.

Comment: Читайте внимательно. Здесь не о киргизском языке, а об общечеловеческих звукокорнях, сохранившихся в этом языке.

Comment: В сортах спама не разбираюсь. Где ответ на вопрос?

Comment: Зашореность и грубость не есть аргументы.

Comment: А я и не собираюсь Вам что-то доказывать. Так где ответ на вопрос об этимологии слова "собака"?

Answer (score 1):

Слово собака встречается не только в вост.-слав. языках, но и польском, верх. силезском, кашуб., и древняя родина славян, возможно, на Дунае (согласно Шафарику, (О.Н.Трубачев, Труды по этимологии. Т.1, С.19-20). Возникло в ареале других (древних) европейцев (фр. chien - собака, ср. щенок; исп. perro - пёс). Вначале "*salvaje" м.б. прилагательным "нехороший", как в рус.: "Вот собака!"